# Files Encrypted when transfered from Mac to windows

Tags: windows, mac, filesystems

We discovered that files transferred from Macs to a Windows server are showing as encrypted.

We no longer have some of the original Macs and when we try remove the encryption it says access denied.

The files were not encrypted (I think) just transferred to the server.

is there anyway of getting these files decrypted or are they lost?

[image: image description here]

Comment: Were these files transferred directly from their original location to their new location? Do you have EFS turned on? EFS absolutely is not BitLocker, EFS is something else entirely, and one of the only reasons that checkbox would be enabled.

Comment: Yes - transfered from mac to file share - yes EFS is enabled and running

Comment: i can see the cert in Trusted People and the thumbprint matches the thumbprint in the encrpytion on the file - is there a way to decrypt it ?

Comment: How would i do that ?

Answer (score 2):

Without the encryption key or the original machine the files are lost (i.e., not accessible)